# Display JSON data from a python file into HTML

Tags: python, html, web

I currently have an HTML file and a python file. The python file uses YELP's API and returns JSON data. How do I display that data onto my webpage through HTML? Is there a function like `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = JSONDATA` from JavaScript?

Please let me know if you need any more details; this is my first time posting and first time using an API/making a website. I understand the JSON data is not going to look nice but I will put it into a dictionary and sort it later, basically right now I am just wondering how to display data from a Python file into a HTML file. Also, feel free to link any helpful tutorials.

Found the following Node.js code as it was suggested to use Javascript instead, where in this would I put my tokens/secrets? And then how would I call it in my html file... Thank you.

```
/* require the modules needed */
var oauthSignature = require('oauth-signature');  
var n = require('nonce')();  
var request = require('request');  
var qs = require('querystring');  
var _ = require('lodash');

/* Function for yelp call
 * ------------------------
 * set_parameters: object with params to search
 * callback: callback(error, response, body)
 */
var request_yelp = function(set_parameters, callback) {

  /* The type of request */
 var httpMethod = 'GET';
/* The url we are using for the request */
var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';

/* We can setup default parameters here */
var default_parameters = {
location: 'San+Francisco',
sort: '2'
};

/* We set the require parameters here */
var required_parameters = {
oauth_consumer_key : process.env.oauth_consumer_key,
oauth_token : process.env.oauth_token,
oauth_nonce : n(),
oauth_timestamp : n().toString().substr(0,10),
oauth_signature_method : 'HMAC-SHA1',
oauth_version : '1.0'
};

/* We combine all the parameters in order of importance */ 
var parameters = _.assign(default_parameters, set_parameters,      required_parameters);

/* We set our secrets here */
var consumerSecret = process.env.consumerSecret;
var tokenSecret = process.env.tokenSecret;

/* Then we call Yelp's Oauth 1.0a server, and it returns a signature */
/* Note: This signature is only good for 300 seconds after the     oauth_timestamp */
var signature = oauthSignature.generate(httpMethod, url, parameters,      consumerSecret, tokenSecret, { encodeSignature: false});

/* We add the signature to the list of paramters */
parameters.oauth_signature = signature;

/* Then we turn the paramters object, to a query string */
var paramURL = qs.stringify(parameters);

/* Add the query string to the url */
var apiURL = url+'?'+paramURL;

/* Then we use request to send make the API Request */
request(apiURL, function(error, response, body){
return callback(error, response, body);
});

};
```

Comment: The answer could go multiple ways depending on what you are trying to do/ how. If you are just trying to load the json dynamically, I would suggest loading it with jquery jQuery.getJSON (obviously you would have to load jquery and use it in your code

Comment: It might be easier to just use JavaScript or a JavaScript library to access the API.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do originally but Yelp doesn't have an example JavaScript call to the API and being that I don't know how to do it myself I was looking for a working example in a language I knew, so the python one seemed to be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation. I had to show the IAM users of AWS account in a HTML page. I used AWS boto3 Python client to grab all IAM users and write a JSON file. Then from HTML file I read that JSON file and showed all users in a table.

**Here is the Python code `IAM.PY`:**

```
import boto3
import os
import subprocess
import json
iam_client = boto3.client('iam')

def list_user_cli():
    list_cmd = "aws iam list-users"
    output = subprocess.check_output(list_cmd, shell = True)
    output = str(output.decode('ascii'))
    return output

def write_json_file(filename, data):
    try:
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.writelines(data)
        print(filename + " has been created.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "iam.json"
    data = list_user_cli()
    write_json_file(filename, data)
```

**Here is the HTML file `IAM.HTML`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>IAM User List</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User ID</th>
                        <th>User Name</th>
                        <th>Path</th>
                        <th>Create Date</th>
                        <th>Arn</th>                    
                    </tr>                   
                </thead>
                <tbody id="iam_tbody">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost/iam/iam.json",
                }).done(function(response){
                    user_list = response.Users;
                    for(i = 0; i<user_list.length; i++){
                        tr = "<tr>";
                        tr += "<td>";
                        tr += user_list[i]["UserId"];
                        tr += "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>";
                        tr += user_list[i]["UserName"];
                        tr += "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>";
                        tr += user_list[i]["Path"];
                        tr += "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>";
                        tr += user_list[i]["CreateDate"];
                        tr += "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>";
                        tr += user_list[i]["Arn"];
                        tr += "</td>";
                        tr += "<tr>";
                        $("#iam_tbody").append(tr);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: IAM DEMO OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Ajax to call your API, include [**Jquery**](https://code.jquery.com/) in your html file.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "api_url",
}).done(function( response ) {
    $('#divId').append(response);
  });
```

In Your Html File

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

[**Jquery Ajax Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Would I use the JQuery Ajax in tangent with Python? I need a way to authenticate the API by using my token key, secret, consumer key, consumer secret, and then sign it, which the python code I have does all that, now I just want to call that python code within my HTML file and then display it.